# How can I delete a single entry from a table

Tags: c#

I have a listbox with usernames, and a remove button I want the selected a user (with all entered data associated with that user) to be deleted when the remove button is clicked.

My code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAMES-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=staff;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

string sql = @"DELETE FROM staff1;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

this code deletes the whole table.

How can I just delete the selected user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a WHERE clause to select the required record. You have to get the username of the selected user to be deleted and pass it to @UserName parameter.

```
 var userName = (listBox.SelectedItem as DataRowView)["UserName"].ToString();
 string sql = @"DELETE FROM staff1 WHERE Username = @UserName;";

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",useName);

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements) on how to use parameters in the SQL.

Comment: DELETE FROM staff1 WHERE Username =@UserName     if i use this what should i put in the @ username? the column name?

Comment: @jamesmc1535: See my update. You have to get the username of the selected user to be deleted and pass it to UserName parameter.

Comment: thanks man , so i copied the updated >sorry if im asking stupid questions , i hate sql connections it confuses me, lol 
 anyways in the listbox the table name is (name) so do i replace @UserName with name 
? and if i do that i keep on getting error on debug/  object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @jamesmc1535: you have to get the username of the selected listbox item. What's the field name of the listbox's username column? Show how you fill listbox items.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a delete query, in order to delete only 1 row from the table you need to add a WHERE clause.

Based on the comments the workflow should be something like: you click on a delete button, you send the name of the staff you want to delete to the command, which looks like:

```
 string sql = @"DELETE FROM staff1 where Name=@Name;";

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name","NameReceivedFromList");

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

Comment: i used this one but then it does nothing so im thinking i did something wrong 
 string sql = @"DELETE FROM staff1 where Id=@Id;";<what should i change id to ? the column name

Comment: You can change the Id with the column on which you want to delete (preferable an unique column in order to avoid deleting more rows).

Comment: 'SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAMES-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=staff;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string sql = @"DELETE FROM staff1 where Id=@name;";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", 1);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();'
        }
did this but  when i click the button nothing happens so i mightve done something wrong :s sorry i dont know how to post a code so its in its own square thingy

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the columns from table staff1 ?

Comment: cant  edit it . the columns are/   name / surname / homead / location / position / cellnum / email /  i have a form with textboxes next to that, the listbox displays the names and when u select a "staff" member iit will display all his information in the textboxes, but that i can do , im just struggling to delete the selected user from the listbox,

Comment: Edited answer with more info. For more info on how to edit questions & more you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: thanks!  all column names >/ name / surname / homead / location / position / cellnum / email
listbox uses (name)

Answer (score 0):

When you are deleting you should remember to add a Where clause, it is actually very powerfull here is some examples that will get you started

The following query will delete only one element

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE Table.PrimaryField = Value
```

The following query will delete all items that matches

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE Table.Field = Value
```

You can also have a join in your delete statement for more complex delete queries

```
DELETE A FROM Table A 
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.PrimaryField = Value
```